# Will a bipolar transistor have gain, even if the collector has no curent?

Tags: transistors, bjt, gain

I understand that transistors have a gain, which in proportion to the base's current.

My question is quite simple:

I was wondering if, when the base had a high current (because of gain), it would affect the emitter current, even while the collector was completely off?

Comment: *High* base current isn't about *a lot of gain*. Think of the base current as the *"cost of doing business."* Suppose you arrange with a bank that you will provide them with 100 per day (you commit to this in a contract) as a 100 paper bill and you expect to get from them 99 per day in dimes. (You need dimes for some reason.) You and the bank commit. So, you supply the bank's emitter with 100 and the bank's collector hands over to you 99, in dimes. But the bank's base takes 1 as their profit. The bank's beta is 99.

Comment: Different banks may have different beta, because they want more or less than each other. (Even if the banks are branches of the same larger bank.) Now suppose you cannot find a way to pick up 99 per day from the bank's collector. The contract says you have to. But you fail. What happens? Well, the bank's base then gets to take all of it. So the bank's base takes 100 and the collector doesn't have to save anything for you. And it doesn't. The beta is now 0. (The part you get has gone to zero.) All you give to the bank's emitter under contract goes straight to the bank's base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's only one relationship between currents in the transistor which is *always* true; it's an application of Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL):

$$I_E = I_C + I_B$$

Everything else is *conditional*, including the formula for current gain:

$$I_C = \beta I_B$$

For this gain equation to be true, the collector must be connected to a source from which it may draw enough current to obey it. The emitter must be connected to a sink able to receive the combined collector and base currents. If either of these conditions is absent, then the current gain equation cannot be obeyed. It is possible for there to be base current, but no collector current, or less collector current than the gain equation would suggest.

Current gain is not a *law*, like KCL, rather it's just behaviour that occurs only if the transistor's periphery, the circumstances in which it finds itself, permits such behaviour.

If the collector is disconnected, there's no way for current to enter (or leave) by that route, and the relationship \$I_C = \beta I_B\$ cannot possibly be upheld. Even if there is base current (all of which exits via the emitter, by KCL), there's no collector current, and you can't trust \$I_C = \beta I_B\$.

- \$I_E = I_C + I_B\$ comes from KCL, which is a law, always true.
- \$I_C = \beta I_B\$ is not a law, it's just behaviour of the transistor which is only true when the transistor's circumstances are conducive to it.

If base current flows, it's *not* because of gain, it's because there's a path for it to flow, and a potential difference to push it. There doesn't need to be collector current for there to be base current. If you have a potential difference between the base and emitter, with the right polarity, then you will have current flowing into the base, and this will be the case regardless of what the collector is connected to.

Furthermore, KCL tells us that all base current must necessarily emerge from the emitter, and from this fact alone you can surmise that base current must of course influence emitter current; in the absence of any collector current, then *emitter current and base current are the same thing*.

Answer (score 8):

When there is no collector current all the emitter current is from the base and all base current flows "out of" the emitter.

If you define current gain as Ic/Ib then there is by definition zero gain, but the potential gain if collector current were to flow can be calculated.

Comment: Does this mean that gain can fluctuate (as collector current changes) with a set amount of base current, lets say 1mA?

Comment: Certainly. Current gain is shown in data sheets as (typically) a range of values under specified conditions due to production spread and, more relevantly here, in typical graphs for differing Ic, Ib, Vbe and Vce conditions . Look through typical data sheets for examples.

Comment: The gain will reduce when Vce is less than about 0.2 V. If Vce = 0V, no Ic current will flow and gain would be zero (like the scenario in the question). When Vce is at least 0.2 V, gain tends to be high (about 100). My main point: the gain only reduces if it sees a low Vce. If Vce is high, gain is within normal range.

Comment: @Walter absolutely. Current gain, beta, is not fixed and not a reliable metric. You use it as a rough estimate for how much current you may need to provide to the base, and then design for voltage gain instead.

Answer (score 3):

A bipolar transistor is a current-controlled current limiter.

The base-emitter current is the input and can be chosen at will. The collector-emitter current is the output where the current limiting happens. If you feed 1mA into the base and the transistor has a gain of 150, you can have up to 150mA of collector current. Emitter current is always the sum of base and collector currents because the emitter pin is shared between input and output.

The output of a transistor is a bit non-intuitive because it doesn't supply current. A transistor is like a valve that limits the current supplied by some other device. You typically have a circuit where a voltage source, a load, and a transistor (collector and emitter pins) are connected in series. The voltage source is powerful enough to supply more than the maximum load current and the transistor limits it to the desired value, as controlled by base current.

Answer (score 2):

However large the base current happens to be, all of it will flow in the emitter circuit irrespective of how much collector current there is. If the collector is left unconnected then Ie = Ib.

Comment: As long as there is collector? I thouht base ane collector had to be on for emitter to flow?

Comment: @Walter No. The base controls the collector but the collector doesn't control the base (other than parasitic capacitance, maybe)